# SWF (flash) object rendering

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I would like to ask when swf object rendering at the html page? Is it rendered only it's visible? If swf at the page bottom that is not visible, will swf be rendered when I scroll down?

The problem is that swf object raises some events when it's rendered and I would like to force rendering even if swf object is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a **browser** issue, not something that's intended by SWFObject.

Anyway, you might try embedding the Flash object in some other way and see if it renders while not in the scroll area.

Comment: thx for reply. What other ways do you mean? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in firefox and Internet Explorer. The only way I found to force the rendering is to set the wmode to **window**.

But IE and Firefox not really appreciate this option and the performance decreased. It's visible when I scroll down...

Does someone have succeeded to rendering flash out of window and with wmode=opaque/transparent ?